# Conditional Domain Redirects in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently set up a server with wordpress and am looking for a way to conditionally redirect to a different server/subdomain set using .htaccess files.

Ideally, it will function as follows:

1. User navigates to http://sub1.domain.com/foo/ (Wordpress host)
2. Check if file/folder exists in that webspace
3. - If 'foo' exists on the wordpress webspace, load it and be done
   - If it does not exist, check http://sub2.domain.com/foo
4. - If it exists on the second server, redirect the client to sub2.domain.com/foo
   - If it does not exist, let wordpress handle it at index.php

Is this even possible?

Comment: You probably want to do the redirect in wordpress, since the htaccess file routes *everything* to wordpress' `index.php`, so it has no clue what exists or what doesn't

Comment: Actually the htaccess file that comes with WordPress checks the local server space first, before routing to WordPress... My goal is tonjust have it check another webspace as well.